# translateY not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working with CSS3 animations, and I cannot get "translate Y" to work! In the code below, the opacity animations and everything else works just fine, so I know the animation is being triggered. But for some reason, the translateY will not take place. I've tried using "text-transform" instead of just "transform", and I've tried writing "-webkit-transform", as well. I also tried using a 0 in the coordinates, so it would be "translateY(0,10px)" Right now, I'm just working in Chrome.

Does anything look fishy here? If anyone has any ideas, I'd be super grateful! Here's the CSS:

```
    .contulmenufirst{
   -webkit-animation: contulmenu 2.5s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes contulmenu{
    0%{
    opacity:0;          
    }

   25%{
    transform:translateY(10px);
    }

   50%{
    transform:translateY(20px);
     }
    75%{
    transform:translateY(50px);
    }
    100%{
    opacity:1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: 2 years late, but I just came across the same issue. The problem I had was that I had changed a div to a span and transform seemed to only work with `display: block`, in case anybody else comes across this page (it was the first one on Google results, grr).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it is not working, I put your `tanslateY` into a fiddle an it works as expected, maybe a syntax error that I did not catch?

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/avocyf33/13/

```
 div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position :relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
   0%{opacity:0;}
   25%{transform:translateY(10px);}
   50%{transform:translateY(20px);}
   75%{transform:translateY(50px);}
   100%{opacity:1;}
}
```